# I have added a relationship between two existing entity but i am facing the below issues?

Tags: ios, objective-c

[image]
I have added a relationship between two existing entity but i am facing the below issues ?

> reason=Can't find or automatically infer mapping model for migration,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x60000104a290 {Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain
>   Code=134190 \"(null)\" UserInfo={entity=Task, property=tskNotify,
>   reason=Can not map from a to-many to a to-one relationship}}}"; }

I did this ,
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you previously installed the app - delete it and rebuild the app. The issue is because you had changed the Entity and did not implement the versions of Core Data.

If you are going to change Entity params in future after release do not forget to implement versions in your Core Data.